# Visibility of a deleted answer

Tags: discussion

Alice has posted an answer to Bob's thread.  The answer doesn't conform to StackExchange standards.  In fact, it's a question posted as an answer (although, it's a reasonably well-formulated question).  Alice's post is duly flagged as "not an answer" and deleted by the mods.

My question is: can Alice still see her own deleted post and comments made on it (albeit marked as deleted and invisible to the public at large) ?

It would be nice if it were visible to Alice.  Then she can use the text and post it a proper question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes. See this update on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/161579) for the details. Basically, it's not listed anywhere, but you can still link to it and see it.